# How to loop python game but also make it cleaner?

Tags: python-3.x

**I'm having trouble in looping this game but also making it cleaner. I'm very new to coding so I do not have a lot of knowledge about python.**
In the game of Lucky Sevens, the player rolls a pair of dice. If the dots add up to 7, the player wins $4; otherwise, the player loses $1. Suppose that, to entice the gullible, a casino tells players that there are many ways to win: (1, 6), (2, 5), and soon.
    Your challenge is to write a program that demonstrates the futility of playing the game. Your Python program should take as input the amount of money that the player wants to put into the pot, and play the game until the pot is empty.

```
The program should have at least TWO functions (Input validation and Sum of the dots of user’s two dice). Like the program 1, your code should be user-friendly and able to handle all possible user input. The game should be able to allow a user to ply several times.

The program should print a table as following:

Number of rolls     Win or Loss     Current value of the pot  
          1                Put          $10
          2                Win          $14
          3                Loss         $11
```

This is what I got so far. I mainly have trouble with the restart()

```
import random

pot = 0
number_rolls = []
winloss = [0]
valuepot = []
rollcounter = 0
maxpot = 0

def confirmation():
    user_input = input ("How much would you like to add to the pot?")
    try:
        global pot
        pot = int(user_input)
        if(pot > 0):
            valuepot.append(pot)
    else:
        print("Please enter a positive number.")
        confirmation()
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter an integer.")
        confirmation()

def dice_roll():
    global pot
    global rollcounter
    global number_rolls
    global winloss
    global maxpot
    dice1 = random.randint(1,6)
    dice2 = random.randint(1,6)
    dicetotal = dice1 + dice2
    if pot > 0:
        if dicetotal == 7:
            pot += 4
            rollcounter += 1
            number_rolls.append(rollcounter)
            valuepot.append(pot)
            winloss.append("Win")
            if pot > maxpot:
                maxpot = pot
        dice_roll()
    elif dicetotal != 7:
        pot -= 1
        rollcounter += 1
        number_rolls.append(rollcounter)
        valuepot.append(pot)
        winloss.append("Loss")
        if pot > maxpot:
            maxpot = pot
        dice_roll()
    else:
        print("Number of rolls", '\t', "Win or Loss", '\t', "Current Value of Pot")  
        for number_rolls in number_rolls:
            print(number_rolls, '\t\t\t\t\t\t', winloss[number_rolls], '\t\t\t', valuepot[number_rolls])

def restart():
    try:
        userinput =(input('Would you like to try again? Type "yes" or "no"'))
        if userinput == ('yes'):
            confirmation()
            dice_roll()
        if userinput == ('no'):
            print("Thank you for playing, Bye-bye!")
            exit()
        else:
            print('Please type "yes" or "no"')
            return
    except ValueError:
        print('Please type "yes" or "no"')

confirmation()
dice_roll()
print('You lost your money after', rollcounter,'rolls of plays')
print('The maximum amount of money in the pot during the playing is $', maxpot)
restart()
```

I get
        Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "XXXXX", line 77, in 
        restart()
      File "XXXXX", line 62, in restart
        dice_roll()
      File "XXXXX", line 46, in dice_roll
        number_rolls.append(rollcounter)
    AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, you have posted your code as an Image, how is anyone expected to replicate this, No one has the time to type the code one line at a time, please go through [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimum complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry about that. I looked through what you linked me and edited my post.

Comment: Now also your code is not indented, can you check it

Comment: `for number_rolls in number_rolls:` - very bad idea to use the same name for iterator as for its collection. It's also the cause of your problem: now `number_rolls` is an integer variable which, I think, equals the last element in the collection.

Comment: Is there an easy way to fix this without changing the rest?

Answer (score 1):

Good evening, I rewrote the program following a small pseudocode write-up. That can help a programmer organize their thoughts before even writing code. Think of it as the outline for your code, a flowchart from the pseudocode can help visualize the code if you are a visual learner. If you would like to see the pseudocode please let me know in the comments and I will add it as an edit.

    This should provide what you need, but please read through the comments as they explain what is going on inside the code. As this code follows closer to the functional paradigm of programming, Python is argued to be both for Object-Oriented and Functional programming. Both have their pros and cons, but that is a concept that is highly recommended to understand as it will make most code's logic flow understandable. Have a good night and if you have any further question please feel free to leave comments or if I forgot something please let me know ASAP.
    As for the experienced people, if I said something wrong above please correct it. Thank you for the help in advance.

```
import random

def playRound(budget: int) -> tuple:
    """ 
        The values are calculated directly inside the params so
        that the Garabage Collector can know the memory is free. 
        While not import here, it is still an important thing to 
        be aware of in any program.    
    """
    sum = sumOfDice(random.randint(1,6), random.randint(1,6))
    if sum == 7:
        budget += 4
        return ("Win",budget)
    else:
        budget -= 1
        return ("Loss",budget)

def sumOfDice(die1: int, die2: int) -> int:
        return die1 + die2

def haveMoney(budget: int) -> bool:
    # This is a ternary expression it is an if statement in one line
    #     Truthy   Expression      Falsy
    return True if budget > 0 else False

def main():
    numRolls = 0

    """
        This is a template string, not to be confused with an F-String.
        The user may use str.format(args*,kwargs**) to unpack into it.
        In english, kwargs pass keyword with value and it will fill 
        respectively. For args, pass in order as each number represents 
        an index to fill the values respectively.
    """
    outputString = "\t{0}\t\t{1}\t\t{2}"

    # To prevent a type error, the string is explicitly converted to int
    budget = int(input("What is your gambling budget?"))

    # \t is the metacharacter representing a tab
    print("Number of rolls\t\tWin or Loss\tCurrent value of the pot")

    print(outputString.format(numRolls, "Put", budget))

    # The return value is a boolean type, thus the output is the expression
    while haveMoney(budget):
        # Python does not support the pre-increment or post-crement operator
        numRolls += 1
        output = playRound(budget)
        budget = output[1]
        print(outputString.format(numRolls, output[0], output[1]))

    print("Sorry you're out of money")    

# Entry point for a Python program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    # Your solution works but it does not need a dedicated funct
    while True:
        userIn = input("Would you like to play again?")
        if 'yes' == userIn:
            main()
        else:
            print("Goodbye")
            break
```

If you would like to use an external file this is one way:

```
import efficent_lucky_sevens

def main():
    while True:
        efficent_lucky_sevens.main()
        userIn = input("Would you like to play again?")
        if 'yes' == userIn:
            efficent_lucky_sevens.main()
        else:
            print("Goodbye")
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: This is actually a lot  cleaner looking than mines. Thanks a lot. The notes are really helpful. I do have trouble trying to made a def to be able to run it again on userinput

Comment: So you can just loop calling this python file, every time the main is called the program will run. If needed I can append the answer with an example.

Comment: Can you? I tried using the only method I know and I get errors

Comment: Mind posting that method please and I will append my answer in the mean time?

Comment: def restart():
    while True:
        userinput = input('If you would like to play again, please type yes, if no, type anything else.')
        if userinput == ('yes'):
            main()
            
        else:
          print('Thank you for playing!')
          exit()

Comment: Nvm I think what I did does work. Im editing it somemore to see if I can get it the way I want

Comment: Edited with requested changes, if you wanted you could change the entry to use your restart method as well instead too.

Comment: Ahh, I like your internal method more. Thanks a lot. For your code, how would you add in "print('You lost your money after', rollcounter,'rolls of plays')
print('The maximum amount of money in the pot during the playing is $', maxpot)" parts from my code? Theres a few new things from your code I have not learned yet so I have trouble understanding parts of it.

Comment: I will add it into the code for you. Please give me a minute or so.

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out. You've been a biig help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Of course, happy to help and I hope you learned something. Please accept the answer and have a good night.